# Checking a user's file exists, from a daemon

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macos, qt

I have a daemon application, which is run via launchd and runs as its own user.

Using Qt, I have come across an issue with [QFileInfo::exists](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#exists). If the file resides in a user's folder, that file is inaccessible and exists() returns false.

The daemon needs to know if a given file path is a path to a file (if it exists), even if it is in a folder belonging to another user, though it need not access the file.

Obviously, trying to open the file in this instance will fail and the documentation for [stat](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) states:

> all directories listed in the path name leading to the file must be searchable

So the function 'stat' is also out, as is [access](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/access.2.html).

As the daemon has been developed with Qt, creating a separate XPC helper app is also going to be a problem, unless someone can advise how to do this, without XCode!

For security, I really don't want to have to run the daemon as root, so is there any way for the daemon to correctly check if the file exists, perhaps by adding it to a specific group, or using a function from C, C++ or Objective-C?

Note that being a member of the "Administrators" group also fails to allow access to the file.